# Long text in long_table

Tags: longtable, columns

I am trying to make a `longtable`: 5 columns, the second column is of fixed width.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}{0pt}{0mm}{0pt}{13mm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\tiny}l} % define a new column type for \Huge
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth} % default: 4in (rather less than \textwidth...)
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \parindent
\setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|p{4cm}|H|l|l|}
\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\toprule
\textbf{\large First entry} & \textbf{\large Second Entry} & \textbf{\large Third entries} & \textbf{\large 4th entry} & \textbf{\large 5th entry} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\toprule
\textbf{\large  First entry} & \textbf{\large Second Entry} & \textbf{\large Third entries} & \textbf{\large 4th entry} & \textbf{\large 5th entry}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
    1 & \lipsum[1-2]  & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I expect a big chunks of text to be in the second (i.e. fixed-width) column. I have noticed that when I place a long text, the table does not compile quite right. The question is more theoretical now, as I do not expect to have something as long as `\lipsum[1-2]`, but I would like to know what causes the problem and how it can be fixed (in case I encounter something of this sort). Many thanks!

Comment: a page break can not occur within a cell so longtable can't do anything sensible with this input, what it doesn't seem to warn in this case which isn't great but it can not make reasonabl eoutput, sorry.

Comment: Wow! A reply from The Master Craftsman! Many thanks for the explanation. So the most sensible thing to do is to split a too long text.